# Error detected while processing nvim/init.vim

Tags: neovim

I just downloaded neovim. I then created `~.config/nvim/init.vim` and added this to the file:

```
call plug#begin()

call plug#end()
```

Now whenever I start neovim I'm greeted with this message:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/shakur/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: plug#begin
line    3:
E117: Unknown function: plug#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I've seen this topic here on SO and its hard following the steps because it seems like each thread starts at a different point. What are the steps to setup the config for neovim after installation?

Comment: Did you install `vim-plug`? If not, its functions aren't available.

Comment: Thats exactly what it was.. I dont know if I should delete this post or keep it.

Comment: @tkausl I'd recommend to write your comment as an answer so this question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

Literally going to https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug and copy and pasting the curl command directly into my terminal (yes I know the security risk) was all I needed to do.